# Node.js read file to array, take one result and save back to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Hello I try to read file to array, and then take one result and save it back, Idk why it save same list all time, maybe I dont understand proper way of working node and async programming, maybe someone could explain it to me little better?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('file.txt');
const pathName = writeStream.path;

const array = fs.readFileSync('file.txt', { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' });
const lines = array.split("\n");

let mem = lines.pop();
console.log(mem);

// write each value of the array on the file breaking line
lines.forEach(value => writeStream.write(`${value}\n`));

// the finish event is emitted when all data has been flushed from the stream
writeStream.on('finish', () => {
  console.log(`wrote all the array data to file ${pathName}`);
});

// handle the errors on the write process
writeStream.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(`There is an error writing the file ${pathName} => ${err}`)
});

// close the stream
writeStream.end();
```

looks like lines.pop() doenst take and remove value from array, should I await function?

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine

for example you have file with content as below

```
line 1
line 2
```

you read the file and add it to lines now

```js
lines = [ 'line 1', 'line 2' ]
```

after that you pop the last element

```
lines = [ 'line 1' ]
```

then write lines into file again and now file content is

```
line 1
```

but maybe you have **empty line** at the end of your file, then you just pop '' and nothing changes

Comment: yes u are right, had empty line on end, but when I save file again, it add empty line again, so cant work continously :( you have any solution to this?

Comment: you can use this when writing
```
lines.forEach((value, i) =>
  writeStream.write(i === lines.length - 1 ? value : `${value}\n`)
);
```